# Get code from country or zone name to set locale() moment.js

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) with moment timezone in it.

I was trying to find how to get code `'fr'` from zone name `'Europe/Paris'` all day, but with no luck.

I read all their docs and couldn't find that function either, so i need help on this one.

Closest what i found is [this](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/getting-country-zones/). I need this function but in reverse, to pass country name and get country code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily i found solution

```
moment.tz.zone('America/New_York').countries()
```

This will get you `array` so you guys can easily pass that value to `locale()`

So final code would be:

```
var get_locale = moment.tz.zone('America/New_York').countries();
moment.locale(get_locale);
```

Comment: This helps. You should tag this as answered.

Comment: @duduwe here is working code with cookie https://codepen.io/Soullighter/pen/MWKVvvP

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to below code in my Angular(v12.0.5) project and get this error.

```
var get_locale = moment.tz.zone('America/New_York').countries();
moment.locale(get_locale);
```

Error -

[image: moment-error]

package.json -

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "~12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "~12.2.13",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^13.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.30",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "typescript": "~4.2.3"
  }
```

---

Then I found the **solution** in [moment doc](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/) -

```
const get_country = moment.tz.guess(true); // Asia/Calcutta
const get_locale = moment.locale(get_country); // en
```

Comment: .guess is taking current user zone, you can't pass custom zone i think